Two directories with different permission and inode #s but same name
My wife showed me this problem this morning - there are two directories in her Downloads directory that both have the same name but different inode numbers and permissions:
20:09 [roar@roar-IdeaPad3-17ITL6:~/Downloads] $ ll -id Screen*
12062130 -rw-rw-r-- 1 roar roar  549975 Apr 29  2021 Screenshot_20210429-182640_Chrome.jpg
12062131 -rw-rw-r-- 1 roar roar  140995 May 25  2021 Screenshot_20210525-091647_Zoom.jpg
12062128 -rw-rw-r-- 1 roar roar  778546 Nov 29  2021 Screenshot_2021-11-29_12-22-39.png
12062129 -rw-rw-r-- 1 roar roar  776636 Nov 29  2021 Screenshot_2021-11-29_12-22-52.png
12077630 -rw-rw-r-- 1 roar roar 1931853 Nov 10  2022 Screenshot_2022-11-10_17-55-54.png
12078209 -rw-rw-r-- 1 roar roar 1066620 Feb 20  2023 Screenshot_2023-02-20_10-52-30.png
12081923 -rw-rw-r-- 1 roar roar  576796 Apr  9 12:35 Screenshot_20240409-105539_Gmail.jpg
12583946 drwxr-xr-x 5 roar roar    4096 Jun 14 12:02 Screenshots/
12091408 drwxrwxr-x 2 roar roar    4096 Nov 29  2023 ScreenShots/
20:10 [roar@roar-IdeaPad3-17ITL6:~/Downloads] $

I've never seen this before, and I'm wondering how to fix it.
The File Manager (thunar) does not show  both, and I'm not at all clear how to fix it (or if I can) from the shell.
Running Xubuntu 22.04 LTS up to date, ext4 filesystems.

They are NOT the same name, as case matters.  One is named Screenshots where the other is  ScreenShots... ie. different characters (S and s) exist in the names.
Case matters for ext4 you're using as the file-system.

I have no idea what you would want in regards a fix, as there is no actual problem, given they've been given different names in creation (even if it was a typo).  You could move the files from the unwanted directory to the other directory, then rmdir or remove the unwanted directory; or keep both.. as there is no actual problem.

FYI:  I ran mkdir ~/screenS; mkdir ~/screens; thunar ~ on my current box (running oracular so much newer versions of software) and I can see both directories clearly in the thunar window that opened... so I'll suggest re-checking your view of thunar or your options...  I could try it on a jammy (22.04) box too, but I'd expect what I see here on oracular  (24.10)
